# Swift String split only available in iOS 16.0 or newer?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting this error on a line of code in my project: `'split(separator:maxSplits:omittingEmptySubsequences:)' is only available in iOS 16.0 or newer`.

But I've used `split` before, and never seen this problem. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/split(separator:maxsplits:omittingemptysubsequences:)) says it's available from `iOS 8+`.

I've tried all the usual "something is wonky here" fixes. (Deleting derived data, restarting Xcode, clean build, etc..)

Can anyone think of why this would happen? What else can I try? My project supports iOS 15+, so I can't just add an availability check here. (I'm tempted to write a regex just to work around this issue, but am slightly worried I've done something else wrong that I need to fix somehow.)

Edit: I've isolated the problem (it was a lot more complicated than this), and it's weirder than I thought.

```swift
    enum SwitchToggleKey: String {
        case type1Etc

        static var childDelimiter: String = "&"
    }

    func handleSwitchToggled(withKey key: String, value: Bool) {
        let parts = key.split(separator: SwitchToggleKey.childDelimiter)
        // error!
    }
```

If I just use a new string for the delimiter (`"&"`) the error goes away.

The error persists even if I re-assign to a string variable like this:

```swift
        let delimiter: String = SwitchToggleKey.childDelimiter
        let parts = key.split(separator: delimiter)
```

Comment: Could you add the call that generates the error and the type it’s used on?

Comment: Yup, thanks @JoakimDanielson, I added code to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the method the compiler is resolving isn't the method you're trying to use. For example, this is a pretty similar method only available in iOS 16:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/split(separator:maxsplits:omittingemptysubsequences:)-7mfus

So one thing to check is that you're calling the method on a String and not on a SubString.

Edit:

In the documentation you linked to, the type of `separator` is `Self.Element` (which is Character in String). Instead, you can use [`key.components(separatedBy: "&")`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/components(separatedby:)-8gl9t) or `key.split(separator: '&')`

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable guess. The solution would be just initialize a new string and apply the split to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers/comments. Please see my edit with code example. I still have no idea why it's happening, but I've got a workaround now, so NBD.

Comment: @livingtech updated in response to edits

Comment: I'm still confused about this. Are you saying the parameter actually needs to be a substring? Not a String? Why does `key.split(separator: "&")` work then?

Comment: The parameter to `split(separator:)` needs to be a String.Element, which is a Character. If you want to split a string by another string, then use the `components(separatedBy:)` method instead

Comment: Is the `"&"` not a string then? Because that _does_ work.

Comment: @livingtech Apparently Character conforms to the ExpressibleByExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral protocol, which is enough to let it be created by double quotes. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyextendedgraphemeclusterliteral . I learn something new every day